# Migrating from mysql to MongoDb,any tool that assist in creating a migration plan

Tags: mysql, mongodb

We are planning to move from mysql to mongoDB. I'll like to know is there a tool or any other resource which can assist me in creating a migration plan. For example ( The table with company, shall move first, then user details, etc etc) so that the migration can be smooth.

Comment: why are you moving? If you can answer that, then you already have your answer.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to know your relations between tables in MySQL without a tool that will tell you what has to move "first"?

Comment: I don't have a EER diagram for my current db, is there a way I can generate one quickly

Answer (score 1):

You can't just simply migrate your MySQL schema to MongoDB (or any other document database store). The way how you would store data is *totally* different. Remember that there are no joins, and that you most likely need to denormalise data, and embed certain data into other documents. This is not something that can be automated.

The databases are fundamentally different here. You need to look from the application side how you read and write data, where you are doing joins, how you can best architect your new schema to work *with* MongoDB, instead of just using it badly as a RDBMs. Search on "MongoDB schema design" to get an overview of what things you need to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I guess, I didn't post my question properly. What I was trying to ask is, when doing a migration of your app from one DB to another, apart from the changes in schema based on the nature of DB, are they any rules, on how to migrate. For example, if you have 100 tables, you may want to start by migrating each table slowly, so how will you select this tables, one way will be migrate the least dependent table first, similarly do we have other rules. I'm not thinking of migrating a table to collection, but something else.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know your relationship of your tables and queries.

1. Group your tables according to the foreign key relationship. Maybe there are some groups only with one table. You can migrate these first. Because that is easy. ex: log, visitor count.
2. Then 2 tables in a group.

   1. If the relation is `1:1`, you can simply merge them into one table and do migrate.
   2. If `1:n`, you can embed the `n` side into `1` side. But merge(embed) or not should be according to your query. For example: if two tables with `1:1` relation never be read together, you can just migrate to MongoDB directly without merge.
   3. Though `n:m` can be implemented with MongoDB, you have to manage large redundant data or process `join` yourself. But if you really really want to do this, that's OK. But the performance may be a problem.
3. If number of tables in a group >= 3, I think you should keep them in MySQL in most condition. But there are still some exceptions. I proccessed 3 tables with `1:1` and `1:n` relationship recently, and I just merged and embedded them into one table, which is easy and the performance is better.